# How to connect with MySQL using a unix socket?

Tags: mysql, go

I want to connect to MySQL using a Unix socket connection. I am not sure how to pass the variables in the connection string. I have read somewhere that I can also use Config.FormatDSN struct to define the values, but I am not sure how.

```golang
// Creates a database connection and returns its instance
func Connection() (*sql.DB, error) {
    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username/password@unix(socketpath)/dbname")
    return conn, err
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So, after some hit and trial methods, I found the solution to my problem. If  you want to connect to MySQL in Golang using a Unix socket connection, you can prepare your connection string in the following manner

```
{{username}}:{{password}}@unix({{socketPath}})/{{dbname}}?charset=utf8
```

values enclosed in `{{}}` are variables.

Note: socket path must be absolute. For example:
`/usr/local/bin/path/to/socket`

I found this reference very helpful
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/+/a48f79b55b5a2107793c84c3bbd445138dc7f0d5/README.md

Here is the full implementation if you are interested

```golang
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type ConnectionSpecs struct {
    username   string
    password   string
    socketPath string
    database   string
}

func GetConnStr() string {
    connConfig := ConnectionSpecs{
        username:   "root",
        password:   "my-password",
        socketPath: "/usr/local/bin/path/to/socket",
        database:   "test",
    }

    connStr := connConfig.username + ":" + connConfig.password +
        "@unix(" + connConfig.socketPath + ")" +
        "/" + connConfig.database +
        "?charset=utf8"
    return connStr
}

// Creates a database connection and returns the same
func Connection() (*sql.DB, error) {
    var connStr = GetConnStr()
    fmt.Println(connStr)
    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", GetConnStr())
    return conn, err
}
```